# Painted Holes for Bookshelf support pins

Tags: painting, shelf, pins

I’m building custom shelves and intend to drill the side panels for pins for adjustable shelves. I’ll use a jig so the holes are even and level and a drill press with a depth stop.

I plan to paint after assembling the case and don’t want to gum up the holes.

**How can I keep the holes clear while painting?**  Must I ream the holes with a hand drill after the paint dries?

Comment: Bits of paper(tissue) should work.  Pull or push them out after the paint dries enough

Comment: I would personally cut a bunch of pieces from a dowel (probably 1/4" holes?) and stick them in there. Paint, then remove before dry.

Comment: I've used metal pins, removing them soon after drying but long before curing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to an airless sprayer that would be the easiest way. You can rent one for a day for a reasonable price if you don't have one. Using a FFLP (*fine finish, low pressure*) tip, with a 310 or a 410 sprayer tip, you can get good coverage with little to no build up around the shelf pin holes. We spray door jambs and stuff like this where there are tight tolerances in/around the hinge pockets and never have an issue.

If you aren't comfortable spraying then roll it with a tight nap microfiber cover, like an ⅛" nap (look for ones labeled for *smooth to very smooth surfaces*) - doing light coats. As long as you don't hog the paint on you're not going to get enough build up that would prevent the shelf pins from seating properly.

Comment: What about HPLV paint sprayer, for slower delivery and more control?

Comment: @jbbenni Yes, an HVLP would work. Just make sure you test your fan on a piece of cardboard first, same with an airless.